# requestAnimationFrame code execution time

Tags: javascript, css, requestanimationframe

Mozilla's docs on requestAnimationFrame states that the callback I pass to requestAnimationFrame will be ran before the next repaint.

I'm trying to figure out how to synchronize code with this.

Specifically, I want to:

1. Apply a CSS class to an element
2. Wait for that class to be completely processed and applied (executing any required layout / rendering / painting)
3. Apply another CSS class to that same element

I want the above to execute as quickly as possible.

Can I use requestAnimationFrame to achieve this?

It seems if I wrap #1 with requestAnimationFrame, it could roll #1 and #3 into a single execution, then apply the paint.  Same with wrapping #2 in RAF.  Do I need to chain #3 in the callback of #1?

Comment: does your class has a transition or animation?

Comment: @JonathandeM.: indeed .. that's why i'm doing this.  #3 is a transition, and I want to make sure #1 is applied before the transition is applied.  There is a #4 that does more class application which I want the transition in place for.

Comment: use the [transitionend](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Reference/Events/transitionend?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM%2FMozilla_event_reference%2Ftransitionend) event.

Comment: I do use that for after the transition.  The problem is between #1 and #3.  I need to make sure #1 is applied (which isn't a transition) before #3 is applied.

Answer (score 0):

I've found one possible solution here, which is working, albeit a bit wonky.

If I chain all of these together in requestAnimationFrame callbacks, then it works as expected:

```
window.requestAnimationFrame(function()
  {
    // apply class 1
    window.requestAnimationFrame(function()
    {
      // apply class 2
    });
  });
```

I don't particularly like this solution, but it is a solution.  Anything better out there?